# Basic ember hello world situation

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

After completing [Ember's Getting Started Tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started), i'm trying to make my first very basic app and am already blocked :)

I just want to do a simple Hello World:

- my HTML contains a text input when a user can type his name
- when the user presses enter, a `<div>` is updated with the text: "Hello user!"

Here is my template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-user" value=newFirstname action="updateMessage"}}
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="well" id="new-greeting">
        {{newGreeting}}
    </div>
</script>
```

And here is my controller:

```
Teamtools.UserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    newGreeting: "Empty",
    actions: {
        updateMessage: function () {
            var firstname = this.get('newFirstname');
            this.newGreeting = "Hello " + firstname;
        }
    }
});
```

When loading the page, the input field and the "Empty" message appear. Great!

But when I type a name and then enter, I'm redirected to a blank `/?` page. I'm sure this is very basic stuff but if I could get help to understand what's going wrong here, I would really appreciate it.

ps: it it can help an explanation, I'm more of a Ruby on Rails world usually.

Comment: I don't see sayHello Method inside actions which should be inside UserController as the template name is 'user'

Comment: Thanks @AbibullahRahamathulah, that was a copy/paste mistake, i've fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with specifying an "action" for the input element - that's the URL you want to send the form data to, so you don't need that as you don't need to make a server request. Similarly you don't need an actions hash in your controller for this.

Ember's a lot smarter than you're giving it credit for. You can set it up so that you don't need to handle when anything changes, as it'll do it automatically. What you'd need to do is something like this:

```
Teamtools.UserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    newGreeting: function () {
        var firstName = this.get("newFirstName");
        var greeting = "Empty";

        if (firstName.length !== 0)
        {
            greeting = "Hello " + firstName;
        }

        return greeting;
    }.property("newFirstName")
});
```

The property("newFirstName") at the end of the newGreeting method is important: it tells Ember that newGreeting can be evaluated to give a property (a computed property) which can be displayed in the view. The "newFirstName" argument tells Ember that this value should be recalculated whenever newFirstName is changed.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this code, but it should be something like what you're after...

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works fine but it misses 2 points: it works like I could have done it with just jQuery. My point was really to use a MVC behavior here (even though, right, there was no model) to extend my understanding of how Ember works. Also, is there something similar to property() that is triggered only when the user types return (instead of each typed key)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean about your point being to use an MVC behaviour - with the level of this example there doesn't seem to be anything more to it than a computed property returned by the controller. Regarding this being possible in JQuery, so are a lot of things. Ember's just a different way.

Rather than using a specific newFirstName property, you could have a model with the firstName property and bind that to the text input, otherwise there isn't much more you can do - Ember tends to have quite specific ways of supporting some situations and this is the way it supports this one.

Comment: Regarding updating only on return being pressed, you'd need to do something like your original code but with {{action updateMessage on="submit"}} in the form element instead. Your updateMessage method will need to go back in an actions hash as you had it originally.

Answer (score 0):

Return false from your action so that it doesn't percolate. The navigation to index is happening farther up the chain of Controllers/Routes that can respond to the action.